# Sharing a DLL between projects

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, .net-core, class-library

Microsoft says it's platform neutral these days, so I'm trying to build on Mac and Linux only with VS Code and deploy to Azure. Why? It's mainly to prove that I can.

Our project has several parts which include a couple of different websites, a Web API, er API and a few other bits. On my Mac I've built a .Net Core Class Library with a load of objects in. Command line, dotnet build, DLL out, no problem.

I want to put that DLL on the Linux machine where the MVC website is being built - the objects forming the models part of that site hopefully. I cannot figure out how to get the website project to reference my DLL and use the objects.

I had assumed I copy it to the other machine, place it in the bin folder of the site being developed and reference it in the Dependencies section of the site's project.json. Nope. I saw a few articles that said .Net Core only works with NuGet and it had to be a package. Is that really true?

I've found and read (if not entirely understood) everything you could imagine on sharing between .net core and .net framework. This is a core-only project so not applicable. Frankly I'm lost, and something called .Net Standard has just rolled into my field of vision.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So instead of copying the DLL, use `dotnet pack` to build a nuget package on your Mac, and copy *that* to your Linux machine instead. Put it in a directory that you configure as a local nuget repository (no server or anything required) and you're away.

I agree it's not as straightforward as a reference to a DLL, but it's not too bad. Note that you'll need to version the package appropriately, so that the tool system can detect when it's changed.

Comment: And we have a winner. Once I got the entry for a local repository in the *correct* nuget.config I was away. I wasted an hour this afternoon trying and failing with that. Turns out I have nuget looking at /users/me/.config/nuget and the dotnet restore process uses the one in /users/me/.nuget/nuget/ instead. Because why not...

So anyway, sorted that, did dotnet restore via VS Code and all is well in my world. Thanks for the help :)